# Return the previous values in the form when the button is clicked (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form shown below. I would like that when you click on the Cancel changes button the values of the fields return to the previous ones.

For example, if I have the word John and I delete hn (thus having Jo), clicking on the button I would like it to return to John.

How can I do this?

```html
<form >
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Cancel changes">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`submit` buttons **submit** forms. To reset a form to the initial values you should use a `reset` button.

```html
<form >
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"  value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Smith"><br><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Cancel changes">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the right question.

But if what you want is a semblance of "**CTRL + Z**", you can save the state of the form in an Object or in the LocalStorage at each user input and reassign these elements to the corresponding fields when we click on **CANCEL**.

There are plenty of solution out there like this one:
https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/89855705204494c6d8bf